# Site responsivo, como testar e como definir @media?

Tags: css, layout-responsivo

Bom, hoje em dia todo site profissional deve ser responsivo, e tenho dúvidas quanto a isso. Inicialmente, há alguma ferramenta offline para simular isso? Por exemplo: simular acesso de várias resoluções, etc? Lembro de ter visto um vídeo sobre algo parecido no navegador Opera, mas não achei tal recurso.

Outra dúvida é no CSS: Quais declarações de `@media` eu preciso fazer para ter um site totalmente responsivo em todos os aparelhos? Atualmente, só uso o `@media` para `768px` ou menor além do padrão.

Enfim, essa pergunta é para dicas sobre o design responsivo.

Espero que não votem negativo pois, ao meu ver, não é uma pergunta vaga.

Comment: O Chrome possui um simulador de dispositivos móveis. Aperte F12 do teclado se for Windows para entrar no Modo Desenvolvedor do Chrome. Depois clique no ícone de aparelho celular que aparece no cabeçalho do Console que abrir.

Comment: Um site responsivo pode ser feito de várias maneiras. Particularmente eu uso a técnica Mobile First. No qual eu faço o site primeiro para dispositivos pequenos e vou subindo a resolução. Sim, usando o `@media`. Sugiro você pesquisar por Mobile First.

Comment: O modulo npm [ripple-emulator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ripple-emulator) é uma excelente opção para emular seu site em varios dispositivos com resoluções diferentes.

Comment: Valeu a todos, agora sim os sites estao ficando responsivo, estou usando essa técnica Mobile First, so alterei um pouco as queries @Media dele

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sobre simular o site responsivo os navegadores modernos já tem uma ferramenta específica para isso. Segue imagem de como acessar esse recurso.

[image: Abrir simulador de device no Chrome]

Ao clicar nesse ícone abrirá diversas opções para emular diferentes devices, se vai estar em landscape ou portrait, user agent,nsimular a conexão da internet etc.

[image: Opções do simulador.]

No firefox é o mesmo sistema do Chrome.

Agora sobre media queries no css temos diversas formas de fazer, assim como temos milhares de combinações de verificações como por exemplo, se é screen ou print, se o dispositivo vai estar em modo paisagem ou retrato etc. Você pode procurar em diversas fontes de pesquisa como por exemplo o MDN do firefox explica muito bem essa parte.

Comment: Valeu, testei aqui e estou com um problema, quando seleciono uma tela Mobile ele não atualiza o layout, fica no layout de dispositivos com telas grandes

Comment: Provavelmente pode estar faltando a meta para responsivo. Tenta adicionar esse trecho de código no head do seu site `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`